# integrate inside angular2 app Google Maps - Place Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, typescript

I'm using angularJS 2 and I'm trying to add `google maps autocomplete` following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#introduction) guide.

I've also installed angular-maps from https://angular-maps.com and been able to display a simple basic google map.

In my index.html file I've inserted:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxx&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete">
```

My app.ts looks like this:

```
import {Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {
    MapsAPILoader,
    NoOpMapsAPILoader,
    MouseEvent,
    ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS,
} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent 
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() 
    {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) 
        {
            var icon = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                // Only geocodes have viewport.
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
}
```

But I get this error:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: ReferenceError: google is not 
defined(…)ZoneDelegate.invoke 
@angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run 
@angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) 
@angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
@angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask 
@angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue 
@angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke 
@angular2-polyfills.js:434
```

Comment: Where you able to resolve this?

Comment: http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/

this guy did it it

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have installed the TypeScript declaration files for Google maps. I found the "googlemaps" DefinitelyTyped library to work:

```
$ npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```